# I want to display a confirmation dialog before displaying output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lift

I want to display a confirmation dialog box like "Do you want to continue?" If "yes", I want to popup a message displaying form output, if "No" I want to stay on the same page.

In the code shown below I am navigating to `facto.html` for displying the output, but I want to show a popup with its contents instead. How can I do that?

My `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Lift From Scratch</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         <!--
            function getConfirmation(){
               var retVal = confirm("Do you want to continue ?");
               if( retVal == true ){
                  <!--document.write("continue")-->
                  <!--window.location.href = '/facto.html';-->
                  return true;
               }
               else{
                  alert("Don't continue")
                  <!--window.location.href = 'index.html';-->
                  return false;
               }
            }
         //-->
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Finding Factorial</h1>
    <div id="main" class="lift:surround?with=default&at=content">
        <form method="post">
          <table>
              <tr><td> Enter a Number:</td> <td><input name="num" type="number"></td></tr>
              <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getConfirmation();" formaction="facto"></td>
                  <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

facto.html:
<div data-lift="factorial">
    <p>Factorial is: <span name="paramname"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
function validateMyForm()
{
  if( confirm('Are you sure?') )
  return true;   // will submit the form
  else
  return false;  // do not submit the form
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateMyForm();"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to probably want to fall back to JavaScript for this one, to be honest. You can make the form an AJAX form using Lift's `SHtml.makeFormsAjax` helper, then you can bind your submit button using `SHtml.ajaxSubmit`. The callback you pass to `ajaxSubmit` should return a `JsCmd`. That `JsCmd` can trigger the display of the popup. You can even render the popup's contents by using `SHtml.idMemoize`.

If you describe this question in a little more detail on the [Lift group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb), you will probably find folks willing to help you with some of the more specific aspects of it.